# Insertar datos de formulario con POST angular 4 API

Tags: angular, formularios

agradeceria su ayuda.
Ya tengo todo el formulario validado:

```
<form [formGroup]="userform" (ngSubmit)="addUsers()">
                <div class="row form-inner">
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
                        <span class="has-float-label">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="juan.perez@gmail.com"
                                formControlName="email"/>
                            <label>Correo</label>
                        </span>
                        <small *ngIf="userform.controls.email.invalid && userform.controls.email.touched">
                            Requerido
                        </small>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-inner">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="custom-select" formControlName="admin">
                            <option value="">Nivel</option>
                            <option [ngValue]="1">Usuario</option>
                            <option [ngValue]="2">Administrador</option>
                            <option [ngValue]="3">Super Administrador</option>
                        </select>
                        <small *ngIf="userform.controls.admin.invalid && userform.controls.admin.touched">
                            Requerido
                        </small>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <button class="btn-simple btn-xs" [disabled]="!userform.valid">Agregar</button>
            </form>
```

Luego de eso mi component.ts luce asi:

```
    export class ProfiledComponent implements OnInit {
    userform: FormGroup;
    userList: AdminRegister [] = [];
    mostrarError: boolean;

constructor(private helper: HelperService, private router: Router, private adminService: AdminService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
}
    ngOnInit() {
    this.userform = this.fb.group({
        'email': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validator.validEmail, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com*$/), Validator.noWhitespaceValidator]),
        'admin': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        'update_user_by': this.helper.getUserM()
    });

    }

    addUsers() {
        console.log(this.userform.value);
        this.userList = this.userform.value;
        if(this.userform.valid){
        this.adminService.createAdmin(this.userList, this.helper.getHeaders()).subscribe(
            (resp) => {

                    console.warn(this.userform.value);

                //const aux = Object.assign({} , this.userList, this.userform.value);
              //  this.userList.push(this.userform.value);

            },
            err => {
                console.error(err);
                this.mostrarError = true;

            }

        );
    }
}
```

Mi service.ts es el siguiente:

```
createAdmin(data:AdminRegister[], headers:any):Observable<any>{
      return this.http.post(this.url +"access/user/create/", {data}, {headers: headers});
    }
```

Bueno ese es mi codigo, ya tengo el form con validaciones, utilizo formbuilder, luego de esto creo el método de addUsers donde hago el consumo del servicio, pero hasta aqui todo bien, la info se envia aparentemente bien:

[image: service response network]

Pero el registro no se envía a la bd.

Quizás haga algo mal en el response o que me falta para que se registren estos valores del formulario?
Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Con postman te funciona?

Comment: En que puerto  escucha tu api?

Comment: Hola, no en el postman me envia 500. Pero cuando lo consumo (ultima imagen) me regresa un 204, quizas tambien este confundida alli.

Comment: Por lo que dices el problema principal esta en la API. Que servidor usas? Es tuyo? Publica los datos de la API en la pregunta tambien.

Comment: El servidor de las apis lo maneja otra persona a mi solo me envian las urls. En todo caso podrías ayudarme a confirmar si el proceso de envío de los datos en correcto? Y veré si me pueden responder sobre el estatus de la api.  Gracias :)

Comment: Segun el estandar el estatus [`204`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) indica que todo salio bien pero que el servidor no te va a mandar nada.(Suponiendo que se apegan al estandar). Puedes hacer una consulta a la api que te devuelva todos los datos registrados para confirmar eso.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, estare revisandolo y dejando una respuesta.